# How to delete GodMode Directory {241D7C96-F8BF-4F85-B01F-E2B043341A4B}

Tags: directory, hidden

a Trjoan has created a folder "com6.{241D7C96-F8BF-4F85-B01F-E2B043341A4B}" under the %appdata% directory.

Unfortuntaly I can't delete it! I tryed with the istruction find here:

https://www.mcafee.com/blogs/other-blogs/mcafee-labs/malware-takes-advantage-of-windows-god-mode/?unapproved=4786792&moderation-hash=f2c6904e23383a6bdd86dae75db17b0e#comment-4786792

but evenif stopping the process that it's running from there and running the command in DOS:

rd “\.\%appdata%\com6.{241D7C96-F8BF-4F85-B01F-E2B043341A4B}” /S /Q

but the system says that can't find the directory to delete.

Any idea?